# Unable to use CircleType.js

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, circletype

How do you include circletype.min.js into html file, and call its function in an external js file?

I've also downloaded the circletype.min.js file into my working directory, however, after following various tutorials, it still doesn't work for me.

Detailed code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <!-- circle type.js-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <script src="javascript/circletype.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/plugins.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="links">
            <ul id="directory">
                <li class="ul_links"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="ul_links"><a href="#">Our Works</a></li>
                <li class="ul_links"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
new CircleType(document.getElementById("directory")).radius(384);
```

Comment: add some live example.

Answer (score 1):

Use these 2 libraries and it will work:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/circletype@2.3.0/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
new CircleType(document.getElementById('type'))
.radius(384);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer this :**

```js
new CircleType(document.getElementById('type'))
  .radius(384);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>circletype-test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="type">About Me :</h1>

  <!--circletype.min.js cdn link(you don't need this)-->
  <script src="https://circletype.labwire.ca/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>

  <!--circletype.min.js file path-->
  <script src="circletype.min.js"></script>

  <!--your external js file path-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your input! however, I still can't seem to run it, could you please look over my edited question, and help me? thank you in advance!